# Necessity and sufficient condition of perfectly normality

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

In Engelking's book, there is exercise (p. 49, ex. 1.5.K), where is written that $T_1$ space $X$ is perfectly normal if and only if for every open set $W$ from $X$ where exist sequence $W_1,W_2,\ldots$ of open subsets of $X$ such that $W$ is the union of $W_i$ and $\text{cl}(W_i)$ is a subset of $W$ for any $i=1,2,\ldots$

$\Rightarrow$ implication is not hard to prove. If right proposition holds, it's also obvious that $X$ is perfect space (every open set is an $F_\sigma$ set). But I can't prove that $X$ is normal also. Thank, for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply lemma 1.5.15 (p. 43) to get the normality. The fact that the $W_i$ cover $W$ clearly means they cover a closed subset $F$ too. It's Theorem 1 in [this note](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/07.pdf) too, for people who are so unfortunate not to have a copy of Engelking.

Comment: oh, how inattentive I am. Thanks!

Comment: @ShorenaMchedlidze you're welcom. Note that 1.5.(K) is the obvious extension of this lemma to $T_6$-ness.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. It's just that while reading the text, it seems that lemma seemed so uninteresting to me that I could not even remember when I needed it.

Comment: @ShorenaMchedlidze it’s a very useful lemma and used quite a lot. I believe this formulation is a didactical invention by Engelking. It “smoothifies” a lot of other proofs later.